# Monochromatic cycle in graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a complete graph with $8$ vertices s.t. each edge is either red or blue. Prove that $G$ must have a monochromatic simple cycle of length 6.

Note: I'm not sure this is even true. Someone else claimed this result without giving any proof.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo I don't know any theory about these things so I tried to prove it from scratch (it's a riddle I found somewhere). I know there are at least 14 edges of the same color and if those connect only 6 vertices then we can certainly find a cycle of length 6. But if the 14 edges connect 7 or 8 vertices things get complicated. After a while I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a paper [here](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=oberlin1370618319&disposition=inline) by Claire Djang from Oberlin College.

In the paper on page 12, she states the main theorem of the paper being

Letting $3\leq k\leq n$ be integers then

$$R(C_n,C_k)=\begin{cases} 6&\text{if}~k=n=3~\text{or}~4\\
n+\frac{k}{2}-1&\text{if}~n,k~\text{are even}\\
\max\{n+\frac{k}{2}-1,2k-1\}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd and}~k~\text{is even}\\
2n-1&\text{otherwise (i.e. if}~k~\text{is odd)}
\end{cases}$$

In regards to your specific question, $R(C_6,C_6)$ is the generalized [Ramsey Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem) which is the smallest number of vertices such that in the complete graph if the edges colored in two colors (say red and blue) then regardless of coloring there will be either a monochromatic red $C_6$ or a monochromatic blue $C_6$ subgraph.  The cited theorem implies that $R(C_6,C_6)=6+\frac{6}{2}-1=6+3-1=8$ and therefore your graph on eight vertices must necessarily have a monochromatic cycle of length six.

Page 13, section 5 has the proof of the case you are interested in.

Comment: The only result I figured out on my own is lemma 3.1! I'd have never solved this "riddle" on my own.